# Google Maps Navigation by Latitude and Longitude not working in some phones

Tags: android, google-maps

Im using the folowing code to open google maps on a button click.myLatitude and & myLongitude are both double values.In my phone it works and says naviagting to some xx.xxx xx.xxxx 
but in some phones it says xx.xxx xx.xxx() and shows no results.Why is that?

```
 public void onClick(View view) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">?q=<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">("  + ")"));
                    startActivity(intent); 

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `Google Maps Android API v2`, which URI encoded query strings for navigations look like this: `google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude`

That being said, your code should look something like this instead:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+myLatitude+","+myLongitude));
    startActivity(intent);
```

I tested it on Android 2.3, 4.4 and 5.0 and it works fine.

for more info about `Google Maps Android API v2` you can look at this site:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation